# How do I copy "*.jar" files from the same directory name "target" in a server (avoid subdirectory under target) to another folder?

Tags: linux, cp

How to copy "*.jar" files from same directory name "target" in a server (avoid subdirectory under target) to another folder?

Example A and B is main folder

A--->>Target----sample.jar
B--->> Target----Sample1.jar

So I want to copy all the jar files to /home/Test Folder.

**Avoid subfolders under Target folder.**

find -name "target" -type d -execdir ls {} ; | grep .war|  xargs  -I  '{}' cp {} /home/test/;

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path/to/main/folder -name "target" -type d -execdir sh -c 'cp -n {}/*.jar /home/Test\ Folder' \;
```

Replace `/path/to/main/folder` with the actual path to the folder that contains the `A` and `B` directories. This command will find all the directories named `target` under the main folder, and copy all the `*.jar` files from each `target` directory to `/home/Test Folder`.

The `cp` command has the `-n` option, which prevents overwriting files that already exist in the target directory.

Note that if there are multiple `*.jar` files with the same name in different `target` directories, only one of them will be copied to the target folder, because of the `-n` option. If you want to overwrite existing files, remove the `-n` option.

Comment: find /var/lib/ -name "target" -type d -execdir sh -c 'cp -n {}/*.jar /home/Test' ;

Errror: find: missing argument to `-execdir'

Comment: #!/bin/bash
find . -name target -type h >> deploymb.txt
input=""deploymb.txt
while IFS= read -r line
do
  find "$line" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name *.jar -exec cp {}  artifactory/ \;
  find "$line" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name *.war -exec cp {}  artifactory/ \;
  echo "$line"
done < "$input"